# Threading model when using camel with Quarkus smallrye reactive messaging

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, quarkus-reactive, smallrye-reactive-messaging

In Camel documentation I read that Camel might use it own thread pool in some scenarios like mention here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/threading-model.html

I want to use the camel connector with quarkus reactive messaging but I'm not sure about the threading model in that situation and I didn't find documentation for that.

In my understanding camel should use the vert.x thread pools (that are used by quarkus and reactive messaging). Do I need to configure that? or it is a default configuration when using  `smallrye-reactive-messaging-camel` dependency?

Additionally, in case of using components with blocking IO, to avoid blocking the vert.x event loop thread pool, should I make sure it will run on the vert.x worker thread pool? or is it good practice to use a different thread pool for camel?

Answer (score 2):

Smallrye Reactive Messaging Camel connector is based on the [Camel Reactive Streams Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/reactive-streams-component.html).
This component uses an internal thread pool (named CamelReactiveStreamsWorker by default) and therefore messages are scheduled on those threads and not on Vert.x event loop or worker threads.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now the default behavior. Is that a good practice when writing high-throughput applications with mostly non-blocking I/o using reactive messaging? or should I change that to the vert.x pools? in addition, is that recommended to use that connector in high-throughput applications?